# Why isn't NVDA reading my custom error alert consistently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, nvda

I've set up a custom html page template for a client's azure b2c login page and the inline errors are getting read back as-expected (can provide additional details about those upon request if it'd be beneficial), but I'm a bit stumped as to why the page-level errors aren't getting read back as well.

**The following are the relevant snippets of html from the template that get rendered during the initial page load:**

```
<!-- B2C-Generated Form Element (all relevant html changes happen within this element) -->
<form id="localAccountForm" action="JavaScript:void(0);" class="localAccount" aria-label="Sign in to Your Account">

<!--B2C-Generated Error Container (prior to error / this html is generated/injected by Azure B2C when the page is loaded) -->
<div class="error pageLevel" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" style="display: none;">
  <p class="remove"></p>
</div>

<!-- Custom Error Container (prior to error / this html gets added to the template by jQuery once the window is ready) -->
<div role="alert" style="" class="errorContainer no-error" aria-hidden="false">
    <p id="pageError" role="" aria-hidden="true" style="" class="remove"></p>
</div>
```

**After the initial content loads (both the content from Azure B2C, as well as the modifications from jQuery), the following logic gets run** to ensure all of the error elements on the page are set up properly (or at least that's the intent) & eliminate some differences that may otherwise cause some problems:

```
initializeAlerts([
    '#pageError',
    'label[for="signInName"] + .error > p',
    '.password-label + .error > p'
]);

// Below functions are loaded & run from a separate .js file:

function initializeAlerts(errorSelectors) {
    errorSelectors.forEach((s) => {
        // Store the current error & whether or not inline styles were attempting to hide it
        var errorMsg = $(s).html();   
        var errorStyle = `${$(s).attr('style')} ${$(s).parent().attr('style')}`; 

        // Ensure the parent element has the role="alert" attribute (rather than the error itself)
        $(s).attr('role', '');
        $(s).parent().attr('role', 'alert');
        
        // Default both the error element & it's parent to be visible
        $(s).removeClass('remove').attr('aria-hidden', 'false').attr('style','');        
        $(s).parent().addClass('errorContainer').addClass('no-error').removeClass('remove').attr('aria-hidden', 'false').attr('style','');
        
        // If an error message is NOT present, add a class to the parent for styling purposes
        if (errorMsg) {
            $(s).parent().removeClass('no-error');
        }

        // If the error was supposed to be hidden dynamically via Azure B2C (i.e. it's a standard error that's prepopulated & simply gets shown/hidden), ensure the error itself is hidden (NOT the parent)
        if (errorStyle.indexOf('none') > -1) {
            $(s).addClass('remove').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
            $(s).parent().addClass('no-error');
        }   

        // If/when the error gets updated, ensure it gets displayed/read
        callbackOnDOMUpdate([s], function() {
            var currentError = $(s).html();
            if (currentError) {
                $(s).removeClass('remove').attr('aria-hidden', 'false').attr('style','');
                $(s).parent().removeClass('no-error');
            } else {
                $(s).addClass('remove').attr('aria-hidden', 'true').attr('style','');
                $(s).parent().addClass('no-error');
            }
        });
    });    
}

function callbackOnDOMUpdate(selectors, callback) {
    selectors.forEach(selector => {
        $(function() {
            var target = document.querySelector(selector);
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) { 
                callback();
            });

            observer.observe(target, { 
                subtree: true, 
                childList : true, 
                characterData : true
            });
        });
    });
}
```

After all of that runs, if the user enters an incorrect user/pass combination, an error is returned to the page (via the "B2C-Generated Error Container") which looks something like this (depending on the specific error returned):

```
<!--B2C-Generated Error Container within form (after receiving error) -->
<div class="error pageLevel" aria-hidden="false" role="alert" style="display: block;">
    <p class="remove">Unable to validate the information provided.</p>
</div>
```

Though, the client wants some verbiage/styling changes made, so rather than showing that message as-is, a "remove" class is added to it (which is associated with a `display: none !important` css rule) and my custom error container is updated to show something similar to the message below (again, actual message may vary depending on the message returned from b2c):

```
<!-- Custom Error Container (after receiving error) -->
<div role="alert" style="display: block">
    <p id="pageError">
        <strong>We're sorry, the information entered does not match what we have on file.</strong> 
        Please try re-entering the information below or you can recover your login info.
    </p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, **while this DOES appear to get read as expected every once in a while, most of the time, the only message I hear read is `"Sign in to Your Account form continue button"`** (which seems to be a combination of the aria label for the form element the changes are nested within, the form element name itself & the name of the last button the user clicks prior to seeing the page update).

I've tried to ensure that the error itself is nested as a child element within a parent element that:

1. Is always visible (from both a css & aria perspective)
2. Has `role='alert'`

(and simply show/hide the error itself via the addition/removal of the "remove" class)

... but I must be missing something somewhere, so any help anyone can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... as it turns out, all of the above code was fine as-is (with the exception of the fact that #1 above wasn't entirely true). The issue turned out to be related to the following...

When the user clicks the "sign in" button, I used `$('body').removeClass('loaded');` which in turn would cause:

1. A loading animation to be displayed
2. The element containing all page content to be set to `display: none;`

When an error was detected, I would then similarly fire off the following commands (in this order):

1. `$('body').addClass('loaded');` (thus making everything visible again)
2. the logic to read the system error that was returned & populate the custom error area of the code accordingly

... so, I tried removing all jquery related to the loading animation to see if perhaps the problem was related to that & sure enough, the error was read as expected.

That being said, I believe the real issue at play here was that the error/alert update was getting completed before all visibility-related changes had kicked through from the css side & therefore NVDA wasn't reading the alert because, from NVDA's perspective, the error was still hidden.

... hopefully the documentation of this experience helps someone else down the road!